# SQL Timestamp Extract Time and group by

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select to_char(Contactdate,'HH24:MI:SS') 
from CHSTAGING
```

I have this sql query that I would like to extract the time from the timestamp. However once I use a `GROUP BY` it doesn't work.

```
GROUP BY to_char(Contactdate,'HH24:MI:SS')
```

Here is an example of how the timestamp looks like in the dataset. I would like to group together the rows with the same time. ie. HH:MI:SS

[image: Contactdate Field]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please show the full query along with your expected output.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? What query are you running?

Comment: If that's the only column you want to select, you can just use `select distinct ...`

Comment: I am using Oracle Sql Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a CTE if it's playing up...

```
with CTE as
(
  select mt.*, to_char(contactdate, 'HH24:MI:SS') as ContactTime
  from mytable mt
)
select ContactTime, count(somefield) as countedfield
from CTE
group by ContactTime
```

Comment: @ALK Kindly make sure you appreciate the efforts by upvoting and accepting the correct answer answered by others to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
Select cast(contactdate as time) as Tim
from
INTERACT.UACI_CHSTAGING_MSISDN
group by cast(contactdate as time) 

OR

Select tim from
(
Select to_char(Contactdate,'HH24:MI:SS') as tim
from INTERACT.UACI_CHSTAGING_MSISDN 
) a
group by tim
```

Hope this helps:-)

Comment: @ALK Kindly make sure you appreciate the efforts by upvoting and accepting the correct answer answered by others to answer your question.